# Downstream project needs to know if it was built by upstream change

Tags: jenkins

I've got the following tree:

```
Project A --|
            | - Project B
            | - Project C
```

When a change happens to `Project A`, it kicks off a new build, and installs the library to a local directory. It when kicks off `Project B` and `Project C`. However, since this is a library install the build system for `Project B` and `Project C` think nothing has changed and don't do anything.

I could set up `Project B` and `Project C` to always clean before building, but I would prefer to do incremental builds when there are changes to `Project B/C`.

Is there a way to find out if the build was triggered by an upstream project? If there is an environment variable that gets set I could then based upon it being set the project's could first clean before building.

---

I am trying to keep the developer cycle low, so that if `Project B` changes, the developer doesn't have to wait for the project to clean and build from scratch, but if `Project A` changes then the developer for `Project B` doesn't care about the build time, since they aren't waiting for it to complete to then move on to asking for their changes to be merged.

Comment: What kind of project are these(Java, C)? What tool you using to build it (ant, maven, make)? The answer to your question depends on the tools you're using.

Comment: These are C projects. But they don't really make a difference, I just need a way to figure out if the build was kicked off by upstream or not.